# Can't render or run python code in Quarto file in Visual Studio

Tags: quarto

I'm editing Quarto file (qmd) in Visual Studio. When file is opened it's default to preview mode and I don't find a way to change it to edit mode.. my python code can't run there. I've installed Quarto extension in Visual Studio. Does anyone know why?

I installed Quarto application extension and tried the setup through terminal discussed online. I expect to see the button on the upper right to let me switch to render mode from preview mode just like R markdown. Also expect the python code block allows me to run the Python code.